# Industry practice for data modeling

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, modeling

I am learning about database warehouses and data modeling. I came across this [blog post](https://www.credera.com/insights/data-modeling-explained-in-10-minutes-or-less). In the section "*DIFFERENT MODELS HAVE DIFFERENT PURPOSES*" the author mentions that depending upon the need of the business, there can be two types of data modeling:

- Relational
- Dimensional

However, in both examples the author says that the modeling is done in 3NF form, I am confused, how is 3NF and star schema both used in dimensional model. Aren't they supposed to be fundamentally different?

Lastly, if I understand correct, the relational data modeling is done for OLTP systems and Dimensional is done for OLAP systems, right?

Comment: The author's quote from the blog post is, "It’s worth noting that there are reasons for using a 3NF design, rather than a star schema, in a data warehouse."  He's not saying to abandon the star schema.  He's saying that sometimes, a 3NF design is better than a star schema.  The author of the blog post is heavily biased towards relational databases.  Generally, the relational data model is done for OLTP systems, and the dimensional data model is done for OLAP systems.  Generally, businesses have a data model already in place from when the business started.